# opera positions div differently than other browsers

Tags: css, position, opera

[image]The div containing the slider on this site http://mhpkg.de is offset by 1px to the left in opera. Other browsers don't seem to have this issue and I can't figure out what is causing this. I had something like this on another site/ occasion too so this doesn't appear to be too rare. I couldn't find a solution to this though so I figured maybe someone did.

Please take a look and help me/ people with similar problem out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparenlty this has something to do with the zoom on my opera browser, I checked it on different systems/ versions (browsershots) and it is fine there. If i zoom in and out on Opera it displays it fine/ offset by 1 px depending on the zoom degree.